# How does Voldemort compare to Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, voldemort

How does [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) compare to [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/)?

I'm not talking about size of community and only want to hear from people who have actually used both.

Especially I'm interested in:

- How they dynamically scale when adding and removing nodes
- Query performance
- How they scale when adding nodes (linear)?
- Write speed

Comment: Niiice! How does a character from Harry Potter compares to a Greek goddess :)... Now that's interesting.

Comment: And who would win in a fist fight?

Comment: @Anton: +1 to your comment except that she was not a goddess :)

Comment: **Sex appeal:** Cassandra is way hotter than Voldemort. Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voldemort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra **Community size:** Voldemort tends to have a smaller, more dedicated, quite violence-prone community. Followers of Cassandra (warning about horrible things to come) are more widespread.

Comment: Close as not programming related, please

Comment: @Vinko, of course this is programming realted, check the links in the question.

Comment: @Pekka: I see my comment wasn't perceived as intended. I would have directly voted for closing instead of commenting about it if I truly believed what I wrote.

Comment: Subjective and Argumentative. There's no criteria for comparison. That's like Comparing C# to Java. The answer is *It depends*.

Comment: This is a valid question as these are both quite recent products and have alot of hype around them, and I need to know people's experience with dynamic adding/removal of nodes and things like that, and rebalancing of data, which varies "hugely" on alot of these products. I'm not looking for a religious war so please stop fighting.

Comment: And I want to hear from people who have actually used "both" products, just so that I only hear from people who know what they are talking about. If it means the question goes unanswered then so be it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Voldemort's support for adding nodes was just added recently (this month).  So I would expect Cassandra's to be more robust given the longer time to cook and a larger community testing.

Both are fast (> 10k ops/s per machine).  Because of their storage designs, I would expect Cassandra to be faster at writes, and Voldemort to be faster at reads.  I would also expect Cassandra's performance to degrade less as the amount of data per node increases.  And of course if you need more than just a key/value data model Cassandra's ColumnFamily model wins.

I don't know of any head-to-head benchmarks since the one done for NoSQL SF last June, which found Cassandra to be somewhat faster at whatever workload mix he was using.  (The "vpork" talk from http://blog.oskarsson.nu/2009/06/nosql-debrief.html)  8 months is an eternity with projects under this much development, though.

Comment: At last, someone who knows what they are talking about. Thanks jbellis, I thought this would never get answered! :)

Answer (score 8):

Some additional comments:

- Regarding write speed, Cassandra should be faster -- it is designed to be faster to write than read (you can avoid immediate disk hit for writes due to specialized way storage is done)

But main difference I think is actually not performance but feature set: Voldemort is strictly a key/value store (currently anyway), whereas Cassandra can offer range queries (with order-preserving partitioner), and bit more structure around data (column families etc). Former is an important consideration for design; latter IMO less so, you can always structure BLOB data on client side.

Comment: It's also important to note that cassandra supports bloomfilters, which allow to index rows by column presence inside a column family. It's very unlikely that you would achiveve something like that with client blob programming.